# How do you change JavaScript highlighting in gedit?

Tags: javascript, editor, gedit

I'm using gedit as a JavaScript editor, but it has very bad highlighting for some keywords, like "static".

Can I change the highlighting in gedit for a specific language?

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 12.04**

You can edit the language specification using this command:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/javascript.lang
```

To remove the special highlighting of `static` change search for

```
<keyword>static</keyword>
```

and comment it out with

```
<!--<keyword>static</keyword>-->
```